# Rails devise-jwt gem is not updating jti in the user after login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple rails app with `devise` and `devise-jwt`. I have the login/logout, etc all working with a `User` as my only scope. But I can't get the gem to update the `jti` attribute on the model after I login.

I expected the gem to automatically do it, but it never updates the `jti`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher

  devise :database_authenticatable,
     :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: self

  def jwt_payload
    super.merge({ custom: 'data' })
  end
```

In my user migration I have the proper `t.string :jti` with index `add_index :users, :jti, unique: true`.

Do I have to manually tie into a login callback to get the jti to update? (seems strange with the `Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher` included in the model)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work manually. Had to make it to the update:

```
  # user.rb
  def jwt_payload
    self.jti = self.class.generate_jti
    self.save

    # super isn't doing anything useful, but if the gem updates i'll want it to be safe
    super.merge({
      jti: self.jti,
      usr: self.id,
      ...
    })
  end
```

I read https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/blob/958cab34287f9985aacc84fedbbb3ea508f6c3b2/lib/devise/jwt/revocation_strategies/jti_matcher.rb but can't figure out why calling `super` would return `{ jti: nil}`?

Would love to see a better method.

Comment: just got the same issue! And solved with your recommendation